# Is setval nextval increment on PostgreSQL sequence thread safe?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequence

I want to increment a sequence by some batchSize in PostgreSQL but I am not sure if this query is safe from concurrent calls made to the same sequence.

```
select setval('my_sequence', nextval('my_sequence') + batchSize);
```

What I am worried bout given the query above is that the call for `setval()` of the sequence would set the sequence back or perhaps abort the query since if another thread has fetched it `nextval()` concurrently.

For example:

Thread 1. nextval = 1001 batchSize = 100 sets sequence to 1101

Tread 2. nextval = 1002 batchSize = 20 sets sequence to 1022

This would mean that the sequence could ultimately return duplicate sequenceIds for for ids between 1002 and 1101.

The same could be achieved using the `generate_series()` function. The drawback would be that the series is not guaranteed to be in sequence since other threads can be calling `nextval()` concurrently to the same sequence which means that I have to fetch and parse the generated series.

Answer (score 3):

From the [PG Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html)

> To avoid blocking concurrent transactions that obtain numbers from the same sequence, a nextval operation is never rolled back; that is, once a value has been fetched it is considered used and will not be returned again. This is true even if the surrounding transaction later aborts, or if the calling query ends up not using the value. For example an INSERT with an ON CONFLICT clause will compute the to-be-inserted tuple, including doing any required nextval calls, before detecting any conflict that would cause it to follow the ON CONFLICT rule instead. Such cases will leave unused “holes” in the sequence of assigned values. Thus, PostgreSQL sequence objects cannot be used to obtain “gapless” sequences.
> Likewise, any sequence state changes made by setval are not undone if the transaction rolls back.

I would assume the above states that is thread safe.

Comment: Pretty much the very same answer at virtually the same time. Now *that* is a concurrency problem :D

Comment: I agree! But hey... two references are better than 1! :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am not sure this answered my question. I have given some more information on the problem.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-sequence.html), it is:

> This is done atomically: even if multiple sessions execute nextval concurrently, each will safely receive a distinct sequence value

Which means, it's totally safe to call `NEXTVAL` concurrently, every single invocation will get its own unique value, guarranted to not to repeat.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am not sure this answered my question. I have given some more information on the problem.

Comment: @hreinn Given that, I'm not sure sequences are even the right tools. They're **never** guaranted to return sequencial results (rollbacks can cause gaps and concurrency can cause interleaving). Sequences are good for getting **unique** values, but nothing more than that.

Comment: I can achieve this as mentioned above with the generate_series() function but I was hoping that the query planer for PostgreSQL would make sure that the table was locked for both the **setval** and **nextval** function in the query. But as you are pointing out, I think that might not be the case.

Comment: @hreinn As there is no table involved, there is no locking taking place. And as highlited in the *Ftisiot* answer, sequences purposefully won't block. The real question is, why do you need them to be strictly sequential? If that's the case, sequences aren't the right tool.

Answer (score 1):

According to [answer](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/13192.1345507800%40sss.pgh.pa.us) in PostgreSQL mailing lists `SELECT setval(nextval() + N)` isn't safe in concurrent scenario. Safe and still somewhat performant alternative would be:

```sql
SELECT nextval('my_seq')
FROM generate_series(1, N)
```